# Не индексирует Google сайт, Яндекс индексирует отлично. Прошу помощи

Tags: modx, seo, google-search

Такая ситуация, сайту на Modx месяца 3-4, за это время Яндекс просканировал около 4000 страниц, все в поиске, как и турбостраницы. Google напрочь отказывается индексировать. Он проиндексировал 4 страницы, и то которые были закрыты в файле robots, такие как search?item= и dev(тестовый раздел). Возможно ли это из за того что я несколько раз удалял и добавлял сайт в веб консоль на начальных этапах? Карты сайта он съел, не все но большинство. Все пытался проверить, блокирующие теги в html, robots.txt, .htaccess. Все отлично, проверял теми же инструментами гугл. Уде не знаю что и делать. Буду рад любой идее. Ниже прикреплю что в консоли и робот.

сайт: https://quickread.info/

робот: https://quickread.info/robots.txt

**.htacsess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maps.xml? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В описании метки [google] написано же, что не использовать! Надо описания читать!

Comment: не использовать что? Ничто не препятствует индексированию...

Comment: Я эту метку сам из вопроса удалил. Теперь ее, конечно, нет. Но использовать ее запрещено (а она у вас стояла в метках).

Comment: Ничего не понял. Это ответ на мой вопрос или я свой вопрос не правильно оформил. Какие метки?

Comment: Метки — это то что у вас внизу вопроса стоит. Вы когда их ставили, добавили метку [google], а она запрещена. Теперь я уже все исправил.

Comment: Аааа, большое спасибо, Глеб!